# A basic doubt about the definition of Convergence of Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The definition of convergence states that the nth Partial Sum converges. Suppose the Sn (Partial Sum) converges to 0. Will that be considered as convergence or not?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, for $n$ is arbitrary.

Comment: thank you for the reply, another quick question: What test should one use if the ratio test for convergence fails?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By definition the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0} a_n$ is said to be convergent if the sequence of partial sums $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k$ is convergent to a finite limit.

In return, the [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) $\prod\limits_{n\ge0}a_n$ is convergent if the partial product $P_n=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n a_k$ is convergent to finite **non zero** limit.

Comment: thank you for the reply, another quick question: What test should one use if the ratio test for convergence fails

Comment: A generalisation of the ratio test is the Raabe-Duhamel test. [See this french page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_Raabe-Duhamel).

Comment: Thank You for that quick reply..